# Could not determine Java version using executable /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am not very new to programming and Java (5 months), but I am pretty new to Android Studio on IntelliJ. I do not want to make an app, but I just want to see what it would be like if I did in the future. However, when I make a new Android Studio project in IntelliJ IDEA, this error pops up:

> Could not determine Java version using executable
>   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java.

I have looked at the other questions and answers on the internet, but I just can't really understand them since I am fairly new. I have also tried reinstalling IntelliJ multiple times, but it never worked. How do I fix this error?

Comment: What IDEA version do you use?

Comment: the newest one. i re-installed it a few days ago.  the version is :  2018.3.5

Comment: Please try to switch to "local gragle distribution" and use Gradle 5 version.

Answer (score 0):

Try below

[image]

And change `distributionUrl` parameter `gradle-wrapper.properties` file to a newer gradle version in file: "`/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`", e.g.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip
```

See https://gradle.org/install/

Comment: I already did the first part but I'm confused about the second part. Could you please elaborate? I'm sorry if I'm being a pain.